# connect() to unix:/var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Okay guys, so this is the error I'm stuck on for days.I am trying to get my `django+nginx+uwsgi` work properly but it's been 3 days and it's still not working, I tried a lot,rebuilded the server,tried python2 and 3 and blah blah blah but the error I hook on is the one above.

Here's my uwsgi file

```
[uwsgi]
project = salesproject
base = /home/ubaid
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/error.log
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
chmod-socket= 777
plugins = python3
wsgi-file = %(project)/wsgi.py

master = true
processes = 2

socket = /var/uwsgi/%(project).sock
virtualenv = %(base)/%(project)/venv
vacuum = true
uid = www-data
gid =www-data
```

Here's my Nginx conf located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 72.14.184.213;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubaid/salesproject;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Now see how the problem unfolds in steps,

First when I go to my website,
1.It gives me an error like this

```
connect() to unix:/home/ubaid/var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Then I manually make the .sock file by `sudo nano .sock` so when I run my website,It gives me an error like this

```
connect() to unix:/var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Then to resolve this I run `sudo chmod 777 .sock` so now when I check my file it gives the final error,The big goblin one

and that is

```
connect() to unix:/var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused)
```

Another thing when i run uwsgi --ini, I check my  uwsgi logs and the logs are printed but when I go to my website i don't see anything in logs,

Can it be because in reality uwsgi and nginx are not actually talking to each other or something else,whatever it is please help me in resolving this.